# Can I use Two Views Simultaneously on the iPhone Screen?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uikit, quartz-graphics

What I want to do:

I want the iPhone to display on the top half, Quartz drawn shapes with some simple animations. On the bottom half I want to use UIKit buttons to draw some buttons.

Basically the animations and shapes on the top half respond to the buttons on the bottom half.

Doing this on the iPad is possible via UISplitScreenViewController. However this is iPad only, using it on the iPhone will cause an exception error.

In terms of code this is what I have tried:

```
//top frame
CGRect topFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 240.0);
QuartzView *board = [[QuartzView alloc] initWithFrame:topFrame];
self.view = board;


//bottom frame
CGRect bottomFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 240.0, 320.0, 240.0);
//allocate the view
self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bottomFrame];
```

What this results is the latter of the allocation being draw while the former being ignored and displaying white space. Both work independently of each other.

Is there an alternative implementation that will achieve this result that has escaped me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your viewController will have a view property. Normally (on the iPhone) that view fills the entire screen. You can add other views to that view.

```
//top frame
CGRect topFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 240.0);
QuartzView *board = [[QuartzView alloc] initWithFrame:topFrame];
[self.view addSubview:board];


//bottom frame
CGRect bottomFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 240.0, 320.0, 240.0);
//allocate the view
UIView *bottomView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bottomFrame];
[self.view addSubview: bottomView];
```